# Visual Basic to Oracle query only outputs first line of results to log file

Tags: sql, logging, vbscript, vb6

I'm having some trouble expanding the way my data is logged.  What I'm doing is connecting to an Oracle database, selecting the details and then outputting to a log file, delimited by pipes.  The connection works, query works, but I'm only getting the first line of data written to my file.  A search through similar situations and other recordset based questions does not return a solution.  Below is the snippet of code that is actually doing any work:

```
sSQL = "select * from MONITOR.VP_EXPECTED_DETAILS"

rsOracle.open sSQL, sConnection
WHILE NOT rsOracle.EOF
    sOracleOutput = rsOracle.Fields.Item(0)&"|" _
    & rsOracle.Fields.Item(1)&"|" _
    & rsOracle.Fields.Item(2)&"|" _
    & rsOracle.Fields.Item(3)&"|" _
    & rsOracle.Fields.Item(4)&"|" _
    & rsOracle.Fields.Item(5)&"|" _
    & rsOracle.Fields.Item(6)
    rsOracle.MoveNext
WEND

oFile.WriteLine sOracleOutput
oFile.close
```

Comment: I would say it outputs only the last line.

Comment: after looking at the results in SQL developer, I agree, good catch, thanks - makes it make a little more sense why it wasn't working with the writeline outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `WriteLine` statement into your record loop.

Also:
While not directly related to your question, you can make your code much less verbose by omitting `Fields` and `Item` when retrieving row values. `Item` is the default property of `Fields`. And `Fields` is the default property of a `Recordset` object. Therefore, they can both be omitted.

```
sOracleOutput = rsOracle(0) & "|" & rsOracle(1) & "|" ...
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, and also thanks for the suggestion.  I'm a novice VB coder, so that's all helpful!